# Rotate Tikzpicture including nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, rotating

Is there any simple way to rotate a whole tikzpicture environment?

If I apply the tikzpicture option [rotate=ang] nodes seem to be unaffected.

In other words, I want to do

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=ang]
   "stuff to be rotated"
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and the whole picture, should be rotated; including all nodes.

Comment: A simple option is to wrap the whole environment in `\rotatebox{angle}{...}` (don't forget to include `graphicx`)

Comment: Does scope support rotate?  I'd test it if he had provided an MWE.

Comment: add `transform shape`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've used package `rotating` with

```
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{turn}{ang}
   "stuff to be rotated"
\end{turn}
```

which ist working for me.

Just adding `transform shape`, as percusse mentioned, worked perfectly though.

Comment: scope does support rotate. It also works.
Thx: John Kormylo

Comment: can you give an example of _scope_. I can not get it work.