# How to keep some text upright when rotating the whole tikzpicture by rotating package

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating

I would rotate the whole tikzpicture by a particular angle. I use the package `rotating` for this purpose as mentioned in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199471/. But the Problem is that I would like to keep the inserted text upright. For example in the below image, the symbol "u" has been skewed. There is a related question in [How to rotate the position of a node but not the text inside it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339235/) but it does not use the 'rotating` package. The motivation is that when drawing a picture it is easier to draw the picture upright, then rotating it because the computation is easier.

To be precise, I would like that the node together with the text to be rotated but the text appear to be upright.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
 \begin{turn}{-37}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw [->] (3.5, 1.5)-- (4.25, 3.75); 
\node at (4.45, 3.75) {$u$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{turn}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the `rotate` key, i.e., add `rotate=-37` to the options of `tikzpicture`. The contents of a rotatebox or a `turn` environment is rotated as a whole, you cannot exempt certain parts of it.

Comment: Just for the records: Your code does not compile. You cannot put a `center` environment into a `turn` box.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer to the question in the headline is easy: No, this is not possible, for the simple reason that the commands in the `rotate` package by design rotate everything within their scope.

But you don't need an extra package. The `tikzpicture` environment has the option `rotate`, which will rotate everything except for the labels.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,rotate=0]
\draw [->] (3.5, 1.5)-- (4.25, 3.75); 
\node at (4.45, 3.75) {$u$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,rotate=-37]
\draw [->] (3.5, 1.5)-- (4.25, 3.75); 
\node at (4.45, 3.75) {$u$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,rotate=30]
\draw [->] (3.5, 1.5)-- (4.25, 3.75); 
\node at (4.45, 3.75) {$u$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```